# Injection between $g:P(\mathbb N)$ and $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for an  injective function $g:P(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb R$ different from this one: [http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable/Set-Theoretical_Approach:_Proof_2](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable/Set-Theoretical_Approach%3a_Proof_2). I found this function a little bit complicated using binary expansions, I would like to know if there is a more intuitive and clean injective function between $P(\mathbb N)$ and $\mathbb R$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you search *this* site as well before posting? This topic was covered more than several times. It's hard to say whether or not the other answers *on this site* are going to be helpful to you, or should answers to your question should cover a different angle.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you're right, I've just found several another answers, thanks for point me this out. I'm going to delete this question.

Comment: You should know that it's impossible to delete questions with upvoted answers. So if you plan on deleting the question, now is a good time. Otherwise, you might want to choose a duplicate and we can vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

An easier, (but somehow similar), way is to consider
$$\Phi:{\cal P}(\Bbb{N})\to\Bbb(R), \Phi(A)=\sum_{k\in A}\frac{1}{10^k}$$
$\Phi$ is well-defined since the sum is at most $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{1}{9}$.

Now, consider subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb{N}$ with $A\ne B$, and let $j=\min(A\Delta B)$, that is the first integer that belongs to one of the two sets but not to both of them. With out loss of generality, we may suppose that $j\in A\setminus B$. So
$$\Phi(A)-\Phi(B)\geq\frac{1}{10^j}-\sum_{j+1}^\infty\frac{2}{10^{k}}=
\frac{1}{10^j}- \frac{1}{10^{j}}\cdot\frac{2}{9}=\frac{7}{9 \,10^j}>0$$
and $\Phi(A)\ne\Phi(B)$. Thus, $\Phi$ is injective.$\qquad\square$